# Sorting several dates by one observation

Tags: r, sorting

I am at a loss! I am trying to sort my data by business_id. Each id has several dates associated with it. I am trying to create a new variable that shows the time in days between the first and last date associated with a business_id. Such that

```
row.names   business_id              Days
1   x8453   DxUn-ukNL27GOuwjnFGFKA   876
```

The data currently is structured as:

```
row.names   date        business_id
1   X27038  2012-04-21  FV0BkoGOd3Yu_eJnXY15ZA
2   X60951  2012-05-14  Trar_9cFAj6wXiXfKfEqZA
3   X60462  2011-10-05  DxUn-ukNL27GOuwjnFGFKA
4   X2078   2010-12-19  PlcCjELzSI3SqX7mPF5cCw
5   X166883 2011-09-29  pF7uRzygyZsltbmVpjIyvw
6   X177828 2010-09-19  XkNQVTkCEzBrq7OlRHI11Q
7   X128628 2012-05-05  6TWRuHn24DL6vnW8Uyu4Vw
8   X202882 2011-12-10  Xo9Im4LmIhQrzJcO4R3ZbA
9   X64569  2012-02-07  Z67obTep38V9HMtA10yu5A
10  X14667  2009-07-18  xsSnuGCCJD4OgWnOZ0zB4A
11  X17432  2012-08-11  XkNQVTkCEzBrq7OlRHI11Q
```

Thanks in advance!

Update:

```
str(data)
'data.frame':   2299 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ date       :List of 2299
  ..$ X2736  : chr "2012-05-29"
  ..$ X160403: chr "2011-08-29"
  ..$ X19897 : chr "2010-09-27"
  ..$ X44519 : chr "2012-05-22"
  ..$ X75910 : chr "2012-10-22"
  ..$ X13052 : chr "2010-07-14"
    $ business_id:List of 2299
  ..$ X2736  : chr "EFJAVVBQQqftuqY5Wb3WtQ"
  ..$ X160403: chr "YDlk9buwF8JQE3JgQgraOw"
  ..$ X19897 : chr "sc1UacpE3cVNJueMdXiCyA"
  ..$ X44519 : chr "VY_tvNUCCXGXQeSvJl757Q"
  ..$ X75910 : chr "fowXs9zAM0TQhSfSkPeVuw"
  ..$ X13052 : chr "xM5F0cLAlKWoB8rOgt5ZOw"
  ..$ X87807 : chr "nLL0sjLdZ13YdvhXKyss7A"
```

Comment: Which row do you want to use for `row.names`?

Comment: I subsetted the data, and row.names just came up. I am not sure what to do with them, or if they are causing some of my problems.  "Error in sort.int(x, na.last = na.last, decreasing = decreasing, ...) : 'x' must be atomic"

Comment: I doubt that they're causing you problems, but you could try dropping that column `dat <- dat[, -1]`.

Comment: +1 for providing the structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `plyr` package:

```
ddply(dat,.(business_id),function(x)
  if(length(x$date)>1)
    diff(range(as.POSIXct(x$date)))
  else 0)

             business_id  V1
1  6TWRuHn24DL6vnW8Uyu4Vw   0
2  DxUn-ukNL27GOuwjnFGFKA   0
3  FV0BkoGOd3Yu_eJnXY15ZA   0
4  pF7uRzygyZsltbmVpjIyvw   0
5  PlcCjELzSI3SqX7mPF5cCw   0
6  Trar_9cFAj6wXiXfKfEqZA   0
7  XkNQVTkCEzBrq7OlRHI11Q 692
8  Xo9Im4LmIhQrzJcO4R3ZbA   0
9  xsSnuGCCJD4OgWnOZ0zB4A   0
10 Z67obTep38V9HMtA10yu5A   0
```

Comment: Hey agstudy, I love the code! but I am getting the error: "Error in sort.int(x, na.last = na.last, decreasing = decreasing, ...) : 
  'x' must be atomic"   I am pretty new, so not sure how to fix.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit now that the OP has provided the structure:**

Your data is structured quite oddly.  A usual structure in R is a `data.frame`, which is technically a list of vectors where the vectors are all the same length.  In your case, you have a list of two (named) lists.

Store the somewhere else for the time being:

```
old.names <- names(x[[1]])
```

Then turn the data into an ordinary `data.frame`, using the handy `unlist()` function:

```
x$date <- unlist(x$date)
x$business_id <- unlist(x$business_id)
```

Use `str(x)` to see the difference.  The names can go back in now, and it's also a good time to turn your "date" column from a character into a proper date, and sort by date order.

```
x$old.names <- old.names
x$date <- as.POSIXct(x$date)
x <- x[order(x$date), ]
```

My original answer should now work.

**Original answer:**

Like agstudy I'd use the `plyr` package, but if you have the "date" column in a date format and want to keep it that way, you could try:

```
require(plyr)
ddply(x, "business_id", summarise
      , duration = difftime(max(date), min(date), units = "days")
      , old.names = old.names[1])
```

This also gives you flexibility on the units.

With your example data, sorted by date ascending with `dat <- dat[order(dat$date), ]` means that `old.names[1]` gives you the name of the earliest row, and `old.names[length(old.names)]` would give you the name of the most recent row, but I don't know whether that is reliable given the magic inside `ddply`.

**Further edit:**

I only showed how to handle the names because they're in your example.  They look as though they were originally column headers from imported data, and R has prepended "X" to them because names aren't allowed to begin with numerals.

Comment: I tried your code but I am getting the same error as the code above.    
    Error in sort.int(x, na.last = na.last, decreasing = decreasing, ...) : 
  'x' must be atomic

Comment: Please post the output of `str(your_data)` (best to add it to your question).

Comment: Sorry, typo, should be `x <- x[order(x$date), ]`.  Will update my answer.